# Don't know how to overlap two widgets and avoid "Bottom Overflowed By 199 Pixels"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I am currently building an app and I have a problem that I cannot solve. I want the blue picture to overlap with the SizedBox (ListView: _buildTodoList()). Doing this I tried it out with a stack, but the big problem I have is, the bottom picture is too tall, thats why I get an RenderFlex Overflowed Error.
**Does anyone know how to cut the excess pixels off?**

Here's my code of the build:

```
      body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.clip,
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    // expand if wanted unlimited in height and width
                    height: 400, // fixed length
                    child: _buildTodoList(),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 370),
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/fancybluebottom.png"))
              ],
            )
          ])
```

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible code

Comment: wrap _buildTodoList with Expanded widget.

Comment: doesnt work (expanded), incorrect use of parentdatawidget

Answer (score 0):

I would consider cropping the image so that it fits. 
you could use a BoxDecoration and DecorationImage. Then, you could use the alignment and fit properties to set how your image is cropped. You can use an AspectRatio if you don't want to specify container height.

Here's dartpad with the below code so that you can play around with it. I tried to mimic what you already had, and put a cropped cat picture on top of it:
https://dartpad.dev/545c8b6ad6d1f6c5aa1c9cc5759fbc08

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Image Crop"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.clip,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 400, // <-- Why do you need this?
              child: _buildTodoList(),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: new AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 400 / 200,
              child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                  image: new NetworkImage('http://placekitten.com/200/300'),
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

_buildTodoList() {
  return ListView(children: [...getTiles()]);
}

getTiles() {
  var listArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    listArray.add(
      ListTile(
        leading: FlutterLogo(size: 72.0),
        title: Text('ABCDEF'),
        subtitle: Text('Author: Shakespeare \nGenre: Drama'),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
        isThreeLine: true,
      ),
    );
  }
  return listArray;
}
```

Also... are you sure that it's the image that is overflowing?  Since we can't see the results of _buildToDoList, it's also possible that the overflow is coming from there. It's especially telling, since the yellow and black striped area is just about the same size as one of your ListTiles. This could happen if you were returning a column of ListTiles instead of a ListView... but it's hard to tell from the code that you posted. What is displayed on the overflow error itself?

I would also consider getting rid of the hard coded SizedBox height.  Unless it's playing a role in your design, it seems to limit the responsiveness of the design. (In order to test that, resize the screen in the dartpad.)

Comment: did this help? If not, please let me know so that I can prove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use `Positioned` widget inside `Stack`.

Wrap the image inside a `Positioned` widget that aligned to the bottom of the screen. 
By doing so your image will render starting from bottom of your scaffold, The only problem is here is that you have to manually specify a height for the image to get the desired outcome. You can calculate this height based on device screen height and the height of your `ListView` parent (a `SizedBox` widget).

Here is a sample code.

```
Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.clip,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg",
                      height: 270,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 1000))),

          new Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              // expand if wanted unlimited in height and width
              height: 500, // fixed length
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 20,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        height: 100,
                        color: Colors.green);
                  }),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      )
```

Here is working dartpad [link](https://dartpad.dev/83a5d6d9480c08f0dfb64390b0524772)

Comment: I see. But I want my blue picture to go below the SizedBox. This code seems to not let me move the picture below it

Comment: Hey @Peoplenco, putting the `Positioned` widget first in the stack will make the image render under the sized box. I've updated the dartpad with that code.

Comment: My mistake phrasing the problem. I meant really not "under" it, but below it. I want the curves of the blue picture just to overlap the SizedBox a little bit, while filling up the bottom pixels. Problem is, the picture is too tall, so the bottom overflows :) Exactly like the picture I posted, just without the overflow error of those extra pixels.